# Android GcmListenerService is not working in app background in OPPO device

Tags: android

I have implemented GcmListenerService for my application. When the app is in foreground I am able to receive notification but when the app is closed. I am not able to receive notification. I have these problem with OPPO A83 device only. Can you please help me better way to handle in all the devices?